# Unified calendar view that is shareable

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

I have 2 calendars, personal (Fastmail) and freelance (Gmail / work). I followed my personal calendar with my work one using a url generated in the Fastmail UI. Now, in my freelance calendar I can see all my availability in a single view which is what I wanted.

I then made my freelance Google calendar public so that clients could schedule time with me. However, I learned the hard way that when they see my calendar, they don't see the unified view of both calendars, they only see original entries on the Google / Freelance calendar.

Is there a set up such that the entries that are consolidated across my work and personal calendar are viewable by clients that can see my availability in a single view for scheduling syncs?